# Accord dans « il n'y a pas [quelque chose] de [adjectif] »

Tags: adjectifs, accord

Écrit-on :

> il n'y a pas de fleur de trouvé

Ou

> il n'y a pas de fleur de trouvée

Est-ce que l'adjectif *trouvé(e)* doit s'accorder avec *fleur* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est un cas particulier: un participe passé utilisé comme adjectif après "de" utilisé comme "cheville syntaxique", pour mettre un nombre en évidence.

L'exemple donné n'est pas très idiomatique, on trouvera par contre par exemple:

> il y a eu dix hommes de tués
>
> voilà deux heures de gagnées
>
> un de perdu, dix de retrouvés !

De manière pragmatique, l'adjectif ou participe passé utilisé comme adjectif s'accorde alors en genre et nombre, comme si le "de" n'était pas là.

Votre exemple est plus corsé parce qu'il y a en plus une négation: tout dépend si vous considérez que "fleur(s)" doit être pris comme un élément seul, ou comme un ensemble d'éléments.

S'il devait n'y avoir normalement qu'une seule fleur ("il y a une fleur") et qu'on nie ce fait, on écrira:

> il n'y a pas de fleur

S'il devait y avoir normalement plusieurs fleurs ("il y a des fleurs") et qu'on nie ce fait, on écrira:

> il n'y a pas de fleurs

L'accord de "trouvé" de votre exemple se fera alors en genre et nombre avec "fleur(s)":

> il n'y a pas de fleur de trouvée
>
> il n'y a pas de fleurs de trouvées

MAIS en tout cas, la tournure de l'exemple n'est pas idiomatique, on utilisera plutôt cette tournure avec un nombre mis en évidence. On dira plutôt:

> On n'a pas trouvé de fleur(s).

Sur le sujet du singulier ou du pluriel avec une négation: voir [ici](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/accord-avec-pas-de-et-sans-a3757232).